# How to subtract data in Access database using datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-access-2007

I have a datagridview which is not connected to database, only one column is in there connect to database which is value retrieved. If the user selects that value and gets confirmation to insert data, then table column which is not displaying into datagridview that can be updated.

Suppose the user selected one XYZ medicine and his availability is 22 after user selected 12 quantity to particular medicine then in backend (which is using MS Access database) 22-12=10 availability  can be update for that particular selected medicine for that I'm using code but I get an exception:

> No value given for one or more required parameters

Here I'm pasting my code and image also please help me

```
private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = null;
    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    string medicinename = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Medicine_Name"].Value.ToString();

    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to insert data", "Data insert Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Medicine_Available_Detail set [total_available]=[@total_available]-1 where [Medicine_Name]=@Medicine_Name", con);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_available", medicineavailable);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medicine_Name", medicinename);

        con.Open();
        int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
        userlist();

        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you calculate the new quantity or where do you have the quantity of the medicine to decrease the database value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's because of the below line. You are not passing the parameter `@total_available`. Uncomment the below commented line and it should work. Also, there is no need to use `[]` around the parameter name `[@total_available]`

```
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_available", medicineavailable);
```

Your query expects two parameter `@total_available` and `@Medicine_Name`

```
update Medicine_Available_Detail set [total_available]=[@total_available]-1 
where [Medicine_Name]=@Medicine_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have a field (or somewhere a textbox) where you user types the quantity of the medicine sold. This value is the value that should be subtracted from the field `Total_Available` in your table.

So you first get that value from the grid row then prepare a query where a  parameter is subtracted from the Total_Available field.
At this point your table is updated correctly

```
private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = null;
    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    string medicinename = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Medicine_Name"].Value.ToString();

    // This is the hypothetical field where the user types the quantity of medicine sold.
    // It could be a cell of your datagridview or just a textbox somewhere in
    // your form. Here I suppose a cell of the grid.
    int Medicine_SoldQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                                        .Cells["Medicine_Sold_Qty"].Value);

    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to insert data", 
                                 "Data insert Confirmation", 
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {

        // Here the field total_available is used in the expression
        // to decrement itself of the value extracted from Medicine_SoldQuantity
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"update Medicine_Available_Detail 
                 set [total_available]=[total_available]-@medicineSoldQty 
                 where [Medicine_Name]=@Medicine_Name", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@medicineSoldQty", Medicine_SoldQuantity);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medicine_Name", medicinename);
        con.Open();
        int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if(n > 0)
              MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
        con.Close();
        userlist();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}
```